# Structuremap Generics with two type parameters

Tags: generics, structuremap

I know I can, in Structuremap, do this:

```
var container = new Container(cfg =>
{
    cfg.For(typeof (IDomainDataRepository<>)).Use(typeof (DomainDataRepository<>));
});
```

but what if my Interface has 2 type parameters:

`IDomainDataRepository<T,TKey> instead ofIDomainDataRepository<T>`

How to tell Structuremap to instantiate this type of classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

```
var container = new Container(cfg =>
{
    cfg.For(typeof(IDomainDataRepository<,>)).Use(typeof(DomainDataRepository<,>));
});
```

Comment: This put me in the right direction for doing `scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IMyInterface<,>));`